# Pyspark filling missing dates by group and filling previous values

Tags: python, pyspark

Spark version 3.0.

I have two dataframes.

I create one dataframe with date columns using pandas date range.

I have a 2nd spark dataframe contains the company name, dates and value.

I want to merge the DF2 to DF1 grouping it by company, so I can fill the missing dates, and also fill the missing value from the previous row.

How can i do this? I thought about left join, but it doesn't seem to work well.

[image]

Comment: NO IMAGE!!! Include your data as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A bit complex.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test1.csv") \
  .withColumn('Date', f.to_date('Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test2.csv") \
  .withColumn('Date', f.to_date('Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))

w1 = Window.orderBy('Company', 'Date')
w2 = Window.orderBy('Company', 'Date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
w3 = Window.partitionBy('partition').orderBy('Company', 'Date')

df1.crossJoin(df2.select('Company').distinct()) \
   .join(df2, ['Company', 'Date'], 'left') \
   .withColumn('range', (f.col('Value').isNull() | f.lead(f.col('Value'), 1, 0).over(w1).isNull()) != f.col('Value').isNull()) \
   .withColumn('partition', f.sum(f.col('range').cast('int')).over(w2)) \
   .withColumn('fill', f.first('Value').over(w3)) \
   .orderBy('Company', 'Date') \
   .selectExpr('Company', 'Date', 'coalesce(Value, fill) as Value') \
   .show(20, False)

+-------+----------+-----+
|Company|Date      |Value|
+-------+----------+-----+
|A      |2000-01-01|13   |
|A      |2000-01-02|14   |
|A      |2000-01-03|15   |
|A      |2000-01-04|19   |
|A      |2000-01-05|19   |
|A      |2000-01-06|19   |
|A      |2000-01-07|19   |
|A      |2000-01-08|19   |
|A      |2000-01-09|19   |
|B      |2000-01-01|19   |
|B      |2000-01-02|19   |
|B      |2000-01-03|20   |
|B      |2000-01-04|25   |
|B      |2000-01-05|23   |
|B      |2000-01-06|24   |
|B      |2000-01-07|24   |
|B      |2000-01-08|24   |
|B      |2000-01-09|24   |
+-------+----------+-----+
```

You can see what happen for each line by adding `.show` multiple times that might be helpful.