# Fill missing dates in two groups and convert data to weekly in Spark dataFrame

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have this data frame with a lot of missing dates in between

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-12-1','2021-12-2','2021-12-21','2021-12-1','2021-12-7','2021-12-1','2021-12-5','2021-12-1','2021-12-5'],
                   'id1':['a1','a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','a2'],
                   'id2':['b1','b1','b1','b2','b2','b3','b3','b4','b4'],
                   'value1':[1,5,7,2,9,3,0,1,7],
                   'value2':[6,2,8,1,9,3,0,2,6]})
```

Which looks like this

```
         date id1 id2  value1  value2
0   2021-12-1  a1  b1       1       6
1   2021-12-2  a1  b1       5       2
2  2021-12-21  a1  b1       7       8
3   2021-12-1  a1  b2       2       1
4   2021-12-7  a1  b2       9       9
5   2021-12-1  a2  b3       3       3
6   2021-12-5  a2  b3       0       0
7   2021-12-1  a2  b4       1       2
8   2021-12-5  a2  b4       7       6
```

I want my output to look like this where the frequency is changed from daily to weekly and the week starts from Monday.

```
  id1 id2       date  value1  value2
0  a1  b1 2021-12-06       6       8
1  a1  b1 2021-12-13       0       0
2  a1  b1 2021-12-20       0       0
3  a1  b1 2021-12-27       7       8
4  a1  b2 2021-12-06       2       1
5  a1  b2 2021-12-13       9       9
6  a2  b3 2021-12-06       3       3
7  a2  b4 2021-12-06       8       8
```

I have done my coding in pandas
Firstly I am filling missing dates with zero values and then in the second step converting daily data to weekly data using `resample`. Here I am using `W-Mon` which means I starting my week from Monday.

```
#Filling missing dates values with zero
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = (df.set_index('date')
      .groupby(['id1','id2'])['value1','value2']
      .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d', fill_value=0))
      .reset_index()
      [['date','id1','id2','value1','value2']])
#convert to weekly data and set monday as starting day for each week
df = (df.groupby(['id1','id2'])
       .resample('W-Mon', label='right', closed = 'left', on='date')
       .agg({'value1':'sum',"value2":'sum'} )
       .reset_index())
```

I am trying to convert my code to spark I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466578/pyspark-filling-missing-dates-by-group-and-filling-previous-values) is there a simpler way?

Comment: I have edited the expected output based on your pandas code

Comment: I have edited that back. Please update the pandas version you will also have the same output as mine. Resample only works with the latest pandas version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, the code is pretty straight forward but if in doubt check the function in the spark docs

```py
df = df.withColumn('Date', F.next_day('Date','Mon'))

df = df.groupby((['id1','id2','Date'])).agg(*[F.sum(c).alias(c) for c in ['value1', 'value2']])

new_dts = df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg(
    F.array_except(
        F.expr('sequence(min(Date), max(Date), interval 1 week)'),
        F.collect_set('Date'),
    ).name('Date')
)


new_dts = new_dts.withColumn('Date', F.explode('Date'))
df = df.union(new_dts).na.fill('0')
df.show()
```

```
+---+---+----------+------+------+
|id1|id2|      Date|value1|value2|
+---+---+----------+------+------+
| a1| b2|2021-12-06|     2|     1|
| a1| b1|2021-12-27|     7|     8|
| a1| b1|2021-12-06|     6|     8|
| a2| b4|2021-12-06|     8|     8|
| a2| b3|2021-12-06|     3|     3|
| a1| b2|2021-12-13|     9|     9|
| a1| b1|2021-12-13|     0|     0|
| a1| b1|2021-12-20|     0|     0|
+---+---+----------+------+------+
```

You may want to consider that you're currently aligning dates to the Mon of the following week. To align your dates to the Mon of the same week instead do

```py
F.date_sub(F.next_day('Date','Mon'), 7)
```

Comment: You have missed summing value2 values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Create a `tmp` dataframe having Sequence of dates starting from the next monday in interval of 7 days from the min of date column. Then join it with the main dataframe and then manipulate based on difference between the week number:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("date",F.to_date("date"))
tmp = (df.groupBy("id1","id2").agg(F.min("date").alias("Mindate")
                                   ,F.max("date").alias("Maxdate"))
         .withColumn("MinMonday",F.next_day("Mindate","Mon"))
         .withColumn("MaxMonday",F.next_day("Maxdate","Mon"))
         .withColumn("Seq",
          F.explode(F.expr("sequence(MinMonday,MaxMonday,interval 7 day)")))
         .drop("Mindate","Maxdate","MinMonday","MaxMonday"))


def maskedvalue(col) : return f"""CASE WHEN weekdiff <=1 THEN {col} ELSE 0 END"""
out = (df.alias("left").join(tmp.alias("right"),
             on=[df['id1']==tmp['id1'],df['id2']==tmp['id2'],df['date']<=tmp['Seq']])
.select("date","left.id1","left.id2","Seq","value1","value2")
.withColumn("weekdiff",F.weekofyear("Seq")-F.weekofyear("date"))
.withColumn("value1",F.expr(maskedvalue(("value1"))))
.withColumn("value2",F.expr(maskedvalue(("value2"))))
.groupBy("id1","id2","Seq").agg(F.sum("value1").alias("value1")
                                ,F.sum("value2").alias("value2"))
.withColumnRenamed("Seq","Date")
)
```

---

```
out.orderBy("id1","id2","Date").show()


+---+---+----------+------+------+
|id1|id2|      Date|value1|value2|
+---+---+----------+------+------+
| a1| b1|2021-12-06|     6|     8|
| a1| b1|2021-12-13|     0|     0|
| a1| b1|2021-12-20|     0|     0|
| a1| b1|2021-12-27|     7|     8|
| a1| b2|2021-12-06|     2|     1|
| a1| b2|2021-12-13|     9|     9|
| a2| b3|2021-12-06|     3|     3|
| a2| b4|2021-12-06|     8|     8|
+---+---+----------+------+------+
```

---

Note that the tmp dataframe looks like below:

```
+---+---+----------+
|id1|id2|       Seq|
+---+---+----------+
| a1| b1|2021-12-06|
| a1| b1|2021-12-13|
| a1| b1|2021-12-20|
| a1| b1|2021-12-27|
| a1| b2|2021-12-06|
| a1| b2|2021-12-13|
| a2| b3|2021-12-06|
| a2| b4|2021-12-06|
+---+---+----------+
```